How to retrieve profile photos from the Google Contacts API?
The Google Contacts API has a few endpoints useful for getting contacts:

people.connections.list
otherContacts.list
people.listDirectoryPeople

otherContacts.list is the most useful: it includes automatically added contacts from various sources.
This is my current API call:
peopleService.otherContacts.list({
  readMask: 'metadata,names,emailAddresses,photos',
  pageToken: nextPageToken,
  sources: ['READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT', 'READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE']
})

I'm successfully able to get actual photos for all contacts within my company, eg: user@mycompany.com
I do not receive photos from various other contacts outside of my company, eg: user@gmail.com.
I only receive "default" photos. These are users I have had contact with via Gmail or Google Calendar - and I see their real photos correctly there. I also correctly see their photos in the Contacts GUI, at contacts.google.com
Questions:

How do I access photos for all of my contacts, which Google seems to have but not provide in response to my API request?
Is it just impossible/unsupported to access photos for all of my contacts? If so, could you point me to a source.


Method: otherContacts.list should be able to access photos for all of my contacts. The statement that I only receive "default" photos is currently happening because of a reported problem. That being said, it seems that Google's already aware of this matter, so a +1 to it would tell them that you're impacted by the issue. This is the link for the feature report: Regression: othercontacts.list no longer returns actual profile photos, only placeholders.

Did you solve your problem?

@JRichardsz Nope, Saddles is right though: it looks like this is a known regression, and that Google discussion link corresponds to my issue.
